# Syntax for a function with (’a * ’b) list → (’b * ’a) list

Tags: standards, sml, smlnj, ml

I am trying to write a function to swap a pair of tuples inside of a list like this:

```
- pairSwap [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6);
 [(2,1),(4,3),(6,5)]
```

I am having a hard time figuring out what I am doing wrong with my syntax while declaring the function. This is what I have so far:

```
fun pairSwap ((a : 'a, b: 'a) list) : (('a, 'a) list) = 
...
;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Edit:
Solution

```
fun pairSwap (t : ('a * 'a) list) : ('a * 'a) list = 
  if null t
    then []
  else
    let
      val v = hd t
    in
      (#2 v, #1 v)::pairSwap (tl t)
    end
;
```

Comment: This is not a dupe of the linked question: that one is about a function that maps e.g. `[1,2,3,4]` to `[2,1,4,3]`, whereas this one is about a function that maps e.g. `[(1,2),(3,4)]` to `[(2,1),(4,3)]`.

Comment: No, not exactly, but both the title of that question and the answers given would also describe this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have provided a solution in the meantime, here is some feedback on it:

- You don't really need the type annotations. You can let type inference do the work.

  ```
  fun pairSwap t = ...
  ```
- You can use `null`, `hd` and `tl`, but consider pattern matching:

  ```
  fun pairSwap [] = []
    | pairSwap ((x,y)::ps) = (y,x)::pairSwap ps
  ```

  This also makes the let-expression redundant.
- As Matt points out, the type for this function is *('a × 'b) list → ('b × 'a) list*, which means you can also swap pairs where the left side has a different type (*'a*) than the right side (*'b*), e.g.:

  ```
  - pairSwap [("hello",42),("world",43)];
  val it = [(42,"hello"),(43,"world")] : (int * string) list
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is my first time playing with sml for one of my classes so I was encouraged to use types to help transition towards sml syntax. I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the variable out of the pair type annotation:

```
fun pairSwap (arg : ('a * 'b) list) : ('b * 'a) list = ...;
```

Note that I've also changed it from what you had to what the title requested: `('a * 'a) list -> ('a * 'a) list` to `('a * 'b) list -> ('b * 'a) list`

Comment: Updated the question to address another problem

Comment: Got it! Thank you